# Package electron app into a single .exe installer with electron-builder

Tags: windows, electron, exe

When I use electron-builder to package my electron app, I end up with a folder `dist`, that looks like this:

```
dist
 |
  - win-unpacked/
  - builder-debug.yml
  - builder-effective-config.yml
  - lemur-companion Setup 0.0.0.exe
  - lemur-companion Setup 0.0.0.exe.blockmap
```

It looks like the setup exe file here has dependencies in the same folder, but I want to give my users a single exe file that they can run to install the software,  How can I do this?

Comment: you can distribute `lemur-companion Setup 0.0.0.exe`. You can ignore the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build directory, the *.exe file is already a "single exe file" that users can install. The other files such as the *.yml files are not important to the main exe file. You can simply ignore the rest or delete them and your build will work the same.